# Nested sub-query to select from more than tow table

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, datagridview, oracle10g

I have three tables:

```
Years (YearId,Year)
Months (MonthID,Month)
Date (DateID,YearID,MonthID)
Client (CLientID,ClientName)
Payment (PayID,ClientID,DateID,Amount)
```

I want to fill in DataGridView as:

```
Client Name, Amount, Year, Month
```

I used this statement but it didn't work:

```
Select * From (select Year From Years Where YearID = (Select YearId From Date Where dateID = (Select DateID From Payment))),(Select Month From Months Where Monthid = (Select MonthID From Date Where dateID = (Select DateID From Payment))),(Select ClientName From Client Where ClientID = (Select ClientID From Payment),(Select amont From Payment)
```

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work".. Do you get an error message? Furthermore, you said you have 3 tables, yet you talk about 5! By the way, have you ever heard of `sql join`?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're just looking to use `INNER JOINs`:

```
SELECT C.ClientName,
    P.Amount,
    Y.Year,
    M.Month
FROM Payment P
    INNER JOIN Client C 
        ON P.ClientID = C.ClientID
    INNER JOIN Date D 
        ON P.DateId = D.DateId
    INNER JOIN Years Y
        ON D.YearId = Y.YearId
    INNER JOIN Months M
        ON D.MonthId = M.MonthId
```

See below for a good visual representation of `JOINs`:

[Visual representation of JOINS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: I think this is a better explanation: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @MohamedHmmam -- np, glad I could help!

Comment: @sgeddes Can I Do That  after your Code   where Y.Year=@Yvar And M.Month=@Mvar

Comment: SELECT C.ClientName,
    P.Amount,
    Y.Year,
    M.Month
FROM Payment P
    INNER JOIN Client C 
        ON P.ClientID = C.ClientID
    INNER JOIN Date D 
        ON P.DateId = D.DateId
    INNER JOIN Years Y
        ON D.YearId = Y.YearId
    INNER JOIN Months M
        ON D.MonthId = M.MonthId where Y.Year=@Yvar And M.Month=@Mvar

Comment: @Sgedds oK I mean I want to Search By Y.Year And M.Month To Veiw Same Date  Understand me ??